# How to register something other than a model in MLFlow

Tags: python, pandas, mlflow

I know how to register a model (e.g. `mlflow.sklearn.log_model()` and then register the model object) but I'm hoping to register a dataframe so that later I can pull the Production version of that dataframe. Any idea if/how that's possible?

I tried wrapping a class around `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel` and doing something like the following

```
class MyModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df
```

But when I registered that model and loaded it later, the `df` attribute did not exist

Comment: You could log the df as an artifact of that model.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in order to create a custom model of mlflow - you must have a "predict" function.

Secondly,
Note that you shouldn't use custom models to save other things than models. But if the dataframe must be saved with your model - you may add it.

**Regarding to your question:**

The attributes appear in an inner attribute:

```
model_pyfunc = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model("model_path...")
model = model_pyfunc._model_impl.python_model.df
```

I agree this is bad programming, but there is no other way that I'm aware of.
(bad because you shouldn't use private attributes, which are attributes that have a prefix of `_`)

Comment: I'd like to also share that this really is a difficult issue that took me a few hours to solve (for other needs in the past)